# how to draw line and Calculate Distance on google map of distance traveled of list longnitude and latitude from

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, google-maps

I'm working on project in which i have list of latitude and longitude points of traveled path from one place to another place. and i want to show  path with on map with poly_Line and total distance in km of that traveled path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Google Maps JavaScript API to draw lines over map:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple

To calculate total distance create GeoCoordinate object for each coordinate and then in loop call and summarize GetDistanceTo result, like in this method:

```
public static double GetTotalDistance(IEnumerable<GeoCoordinate> coordinates)
{
    double result = 0;

    if (coordinates.Count() > 1)
    {
        GeoCoordinate previous = coordinates.First();

        foreach (var current in coordinates)
        {
            result += previous.GetDistanceTo(current);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: can i pass polyline path shown in above link to GetTotalDistance(IEnumerable<GeoCoordinate> coordinates) by using PolyLine GetPath() Method??

Comment: @KareemSoomro, ehm... I don't understand your question. You have some database where geographical coordinates stored as latitude and longitude. It's right? So you want to show Google Map path and total distance of all coordinates on the some ASP.NET page. This are two separated tasks...

Comment: @KareemSoomro, To do first task you must write javascript like in example on Google Developer's help page. But coordinates must be provided dynamically. So you must write some ASP.NET code that returns json-array for example, and then using AJAX load it to client-side javascript code.

Comment: @KareemSoomro, To do second task, you must calculate total distance of all points, and then just write result on page. To do this calculation you can use some method like mine.

Comment: yes i have database from which i read the data and passed it to java script, now i am trying your method to calculate the distance.

Comment: calculated distance by using GetTotalDistance(IEnumerable<GeoCoordinate> coordinates).

Comment: still haning on ASP.NET code that returns json-array and load it into  javascript..